# Set current subchart

Tags: r, quantmod

I am not able to set current subchart for add_TA function (quantmod package).

```
curon = 2

add_TA(x, type = "l",col = "blue", lwd = 2, on=curon)
```

(add a line on the subchart 2)

R is giving me this error:

```
Error in plot_ta(x = current.chob(), ta = get("x"), on = curon, taType = NULL,  : 
 object 'curon' not found.
```

the command:

```
add_TA(x, type = "l",col = "blue", lwd = 2, on=2)
```

works fine though.

NOTE: The problem only occurs when used in a function, not when in global scope. Here is a full example:

```
library(quantmod)

test=function(){
x=xts(runif(10),Sys.Date()+1:10)
z=1/x
chart_Series(x)
add_TA(x, type = "l",col = "green", lwd = 2)    #OK
add_TA(z, type = "l",col = "blue", lwd = 2, on=2)   #OK
curon = 2;add_TA(z, type = "l",col = "red", lwd = 2, on=curon)  #FAILS
}

test()
```

Comment: Hi. A fully reproducible minimal example would help diagnose the problem. Also, the documentation under `?add_TA` (actually then referring to `chart_Series`) has a note: "Highly experimental (read: alpha) use with caution."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must have a typo somewhere, in code you've not shown, as it works for me:

```
library(quantmod)
x=xts(runif(10),Sys.Date()+1:10)
z=1/x

chart_Series(x)
add_TA(x, type = "l",col = "green", lwd = 2)
curon = 2
add_TA(z, type = "l",col = "blue", lwd = 2, on=curon)
```

(By the way, this is what people mean by a "fully reproducible minimal example"; something you can copy and paste into a fresh R session. Unless it matters for your question, the data can be random.)

UPDATE: Having reproduced the problem when using a function, I did find a workaround (for what I think is a quantmod bug). If you name your variable `on` instead of `curon` then it works:

```
library(quantmod)

test=function(){
x=xts(runif(10),Sys.Date()+1:10)
z=1/x
chart_Series(x)
add_TA(x, type = "l",col = "green", lwd = 2) 
on=2;add_TA(z, type = "l",col = "blue", lwd = 2, on=on)
}
```

Comment: thx Darren. I guess it has sth to do with environment as it works fine if i set curon as a global variable but not in a function.

Comment: @SilverSpoon Yes, you're right, I can reproduce that (I just edited your question to show this.)  I think it is a quantmod bug. If you type `add_TA` (i.e. without any parentheses) you can see the source. `plot_ta()` is created dynamically in there. `as.expression()` is used to call it, which apparently means its arguments are not evaluated. I think that is where the bug is.